# Usage of polymorphism with Map and Consumer from Java

Tags: java, generics, casting, typechecking, consumer

I have a class like this

```
public class Foo {
    private final Map<Step, Consumer<Step>> context = new LinkedHashMap<>();
    
    public <T extends Step> void save(Consumer<T> consumer, T step) {
        this.context.put(step, consumer);
    }
}
```

As you can see, I wanna be able to save any class that is a child of `Step` inside my `Map` context, but I get the following error

```
Provided Consumer<T>, Required Consumer<Step>
```

Is any way to achieve the desired result by using generics?

Some things I tried are:

- Changing the `Map` type to `<? extends Step>`, but this throw a new error, because it seems that when you use the wildcard `?` you have a read-only `Map`.
- Typecasting like below

```
public class Foo {
    private final Map<Step, Consumer<Step>> context = new LinkedHashMap<>();
    
    public <T extends Step> void save(Consumer<T> consumer, T step) {
        this.context.put(step, (Consumer<Step>) consumer);
    }
}
```

The later seems to work, but I get a `Unchecked cast` warning on my console. If this is the way to go, I would like to know what are the downsides of it and how would be an apropriate way to check for it.

Comment: Why do you think that a `Map<Step, Consumer<? extends Step>>` is readonly?

Comment: Not sure, I just read a similar post about it here in stackoverflow, can't seem to find it again to link it here tho

Answer (score 2):

The compiler has no way of confirming that the subtype of Step that's the key of the Map is the *same* subtype of the Consumer for the key's value in the Map.

*You* know that, so *you* know the unchecked cast is safe.

Go with the unchecked cast.